# Dialog stack doesn't reset

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a scorable dialog that will check if the incoming message is equal to "resetconversation". When true, the dialog resets the dialog stack  in the PostAsync method.

When the postasync method is hit, the dialog stack resets as expected but when I again send a message the stack reappears and  the conversation proceeds as if it was never reset.

[note]: I have noticed that this issue happens when a PromptDialog.Choice() is expecting an input.

Below is the scorable registration and the scorable dialog class.
Thanks!

Registering my scorable dialog:

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));


                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BotDataContextConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                var store = new SqlBotDataStore(conn);

                builder.Register(c => store)
                    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                    .AsSelf()
                    .SingleInstance();

                //Scorable to check if dialog stack reset has been requested
                builder.RegisterType<HandleResetRequestScorable>()
                .AsSelf()
                .As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>();


});
```

Scorable Dialog:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class HandleResetRequestScorable : ScorableBase<IActivity, bool, double>
    {

        private readonly IBotToUser _botToUser;

        private readonly IDialogStack _dialogStack;

        private bool _isMessageType { get; set; }


        public HandleResetRequestScorable(IBotToUser botToUser, IDialogStack dialogTask)
        {
            SetField.NotNull(out _botToUser, nameof(_botToUser), botToUser);

            //SetField.NotNull(out _dialogStack, nameof(_dialogStack), dialogTask);

        }


        protected override async Task<bool> PrepareAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
        {
            string message = string.Empty;

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
            {
                _isMessageType = false;
                message = activity.AsEventActivity().Name.ToLower();
            }
            else
            {
                _isMessageType = true;
                message = activity.AsMessageActivity().Text.ToLower();
            }



            if (message == "resetconversation")
                return true;


            return false;
        }


        protected override bool HasScore(IActivity item, bool state)
        {
            return state;
        }


        protected override double GetScore(IActivity item, bool state)
        {
            return state ? 1.0 : 0;
        }


        protected override async Task PostAsync(IActivity activity, bool state, CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {

                var message = activity as IMessageActivity;
                string[] data = message.Value.ToString().Split('|');
                using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity as Activity))
                {
                    //get the conversation related data
                    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
                    await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));

                    //get the dialog stack
                    var convoStack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
                    convoStack.Reset();


                    if (_isMessageType)
                    {
                        await _botToUser.PostAsync("Conversation reset complete.");
                        await _botToUser.PostAsync("Hi");
                    }

                    await botData.FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }


        }

        protected override Task DoneAsync(IActivity item, bool state, CancellationToken token)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of extra work in your PostAsync. If you want to reset everything you should only need to call `this.task.Reset();`

Microsoft has a really good example app on reset the dialog stack using scorables.

[GitHub Bot Framework example][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-GlobalMessageHandlers/Dialogs/CancelScorable.cs

Comment: @EdBoykin  Thanks for this, it worked. But then why do they have a reset method on dialog stack?

Comment: Also I noticed that after the line `botData.FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken));`  the state of the updated dialog stack was saved in the database. But as soon as the scorable finished execution, the state was again getting updated in db with the state that was before the execution of the flush async() method. Can't figure out whats going on here...

Comment: The dialog stack and db state are handled separately. You'll need to clear the db state yourself.